# How to batch convert PNGs to JPEGs and preserve timestamps in filesystem & EXIF header?

Tags: batch, timestamp, image-processing, exif, image-conversion

I sometimes take screenshots on my Mac during video-calls with friends/family (with their consent of course!) and would like to add those images of a photographic nature to my Apple Photos Library. I have considered these options/alternatives:

1. **Add the PNGs as-is to Apple Photos**: But a lossless image format such as PNG for pictures which photographic content is a *waste of storage by a factor of 10-20x*. Apple Photos has no function "Compress this file in the library". Hence I need external pre-processing.
2. **Set JPEG as the output format for macOS's native screenshot command**. That's possible. But I do my screenshot spontaneously, hence I would need to switch that option all the time, and until I switched the situation on screen may already be over. So this is no option either.
3. **Hence leave PNG as the default for maximal quality preservation.** And where it makes sense compress in a post-processing later, before adding to the Photo Library.

So does any one know and CLI tools or GUI apps for that purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I)** Use ImageMagick to perform the batch processing from PNG to JPG while preserving the timestamp:

```
mogrify -verbose -define preserve-timestamp=true -format jpg -quality 60% -path ./output/ ./input/*.png
```

- `preserve-timestamp` correctly preserves the creation and modification timestamps in the filesystems.
- But in the EXIF header timestamps are NOT created!
- As I read in a [forum post from 10/2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52957956/#comment92824722_52958139) writing EXIF metadata seems not to be in the scope of ImageMagick.
- Hence the use of another tool:

**II)** Use ExifTool to copy the creation date in the filesystem to the creation and modification date in the filesystem and into the EXIF header of the file.

```
exiftool "-alldates<filecreatedate" -overwrite_original_in_place -P ./output/
```

- `overwrite_original_in_place` causes that this remains the same file, hence the creation date stays as-is.
- `-P` preserves the modification timestamp of the original file which is overwritten in place.
- And the EXIF timestamp is also updated because it's included in `-alldates`.